# Second time binding fails with KoGrid when ViewModel is used with constructor pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I am using KoGrid for my data binding. and the following code seems to work all great:

var ViewModel = {
 prizeCollection : ko.observableArray;
}

Then bind it somewhere in code with PrizeCollection(data); and it works all great when I use it in the templates like following:

```
 <div data-bind="koGrid: { data: PrizeFulfilmentStatuses  , columnDefs: [ { field: 'Description', width: 140 },
                                        { field: 'Order', width: 100, headerClass: 'specialHeader' },
                                        { field: 'ColorHex',  width: 150,cellTemplate: 'editTemplate' },
                                        { field: 'Editable', width: 180, cellClass: 'specialCell' },
                                        { field: 'ID', width: 170 }, { field: 'Who', width: 170 }],
                             autogenerateColumns: false,
                             isMultiSelect: false,
                             enablePaging: true
                             }  "></div>
```

It's all great. I can bind it once and I can bind it multiple times when new data comes from the server and it seems to work all great.

Now, when I make my ViewModel some soething like following:

ViewModel = function(){
var PrizeCollection = ko.observableArray();
}

and use it in conjunction with the same template on the HTMl, the first time data load is not a problem at all. But second time when I load it, the browser gets hung and when I look into firebug, it gives me following error:

```
data.column is not defined.
```

Basically data.column is empty.

I am not sure why it is having problem with the same data. I also tried unbinding with

```
 ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("KoGridContainer"));
```

That was not that helpful either

Any suggestions?